# Problems WIth Multiple Quotes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, quotes

I'm having a problem changing a select's options based on another select's option, below is the code that works:

```
dropdown2.innerHTML = "<?php echo($SQLFormElements->GetColumnAsOptions('SELECT `field2` FROM `table2` WHERE `field1` = \'8\' ')); ?>";
```

**Explanation:**

I have two database tables: `table1` and `table2`. `table1` has the `field1`. `table2` has the fields `field2` and `field1`. `SQLFormElements` is a php file that echoes out html elements based on mysql queries, in this case, options for a select element. `dropdown1` contains `field1` values. `dropdown2` should display `field2` values based on the value of `field1`, i.e. which is the selected item of `dropdown1`.

Anyways, the above code works fine, however i've hardcoded as opposed to getting the value, because when i do something like this:

```
var selectedItem = document.getElementById("ddField1");
dropdown2.innerHTML = "<?php echo($SQLFormElements->GetColumnAsOptions('SELECT `field2` FROM `table2` WHERE `field1` = \'" + selectedItem + "\' ')); ?>";
```

it does not work, any idea why!? i'm kinda stumped. Just a reminder, the first code snippet works.

**I've tried the following:**

- parsing the variable as an Integer (field1 in my table is an integer type)
- leaving out the quotes in the where clause
- leaving out the quotes but hard coding the value in the where clause works

Comment: You potentially have a huge SQL Injection vulnerability. Never use un-sanitized user values directly in SQL code!

Comment: It's not a quotes problem, you are horribly trying to mix JavaScript with PHP. Think of when and where (by what) each of them is executed. The solution is called "AJAX", you will find plenty of help on that on the web.

Comment: I'm aware of Ajax but I've just started learning PHP and JavaScript. So learning Ajax is kinda backseat right now. But if I need it I guess I'm gonna have to go that route

Comment: SQL injection problem? I don't quite understand. Please explain. Maybe I can sort it out.

Comment: OK just checked it out! SQL Injection that is, and it's pretty serious! Security has always been my nemesis, but for now i'm going to overlook it since it is a intranet site i'm working on, mainly for myself, however it is seriously an issue i will have to look at, thanks @asawyer.

Comment: @Bergi, I wasn't prepared to break my head over this issue, so I took you up and I tried out an AJAX method and guess what, YES :) it works. Thanks dude. The reason I wanted to use php is cause it made my sql query hidden from the user. Now with ajax it's freely available, i guess to hide that code is a whole 'nother topic altogether. Any direction on where i should get started?

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed the value in your selectedItem.

`var selectedItem = document.getElementById("ddField1");` change it to `var selectedItem = document.getElementById("ddField1").value;`

Comment: Right, see the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-the-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript

Comment: I'm gonna give that a go. And let you know. Thanks :)

Comment: Didn't work :(

When i use `alert(selectedItem)` it shows what it is selected, however when i concatenate the selectedItem, it doesn't work. Gosh this is driving me mad.

Answer (score 0):

So the AJAX method suggested by @Bergi did the trick:

here it is:

dropdown1's onchange event:

```
onchange="AJAXItemChangeEvent(this.value)"
```

...

JavaScript Function

```
function AJAXItemChangeEvent(selectedValue)
{
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    document.getElementById("dropdown2").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET","Getter.php?field1=" + selectedValue,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

...

**Getter.php**

```
<?php
  mysql_connect("dbhost","username","password");
  mysql_select_db("dbname");

  $field1 = $_GET["field1"];
  $sql = "SELECT field2 FROM table2 WHERE field1 = '".$field1."'";

  $result = mysql_query($sql);
  echo "<option></option>";

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
      echo "<option>".$row[0]."</option>";      
  }         
?>
```

**NOTE**
 - my ajax code does not cater for old browsers \ backward capability

Comment: This still does not address the SQL Injection issue, and also you might be introducing an XSS attack vulnerability if those data elements you are writing to the DOM are in any way coming from user input.  For example - Suppose I use a client debugger to edit the value of the drop down list to `' or 1=1; drop all; --` and then submit your Ajax request. What would happen?  http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Aha I'm aware that there's a huge security flaw. But this is only for a small group of end users. Less than 10 and they haven't even heard of Linux before. So it isn't really an issue. However when I do decide to implement id have to address this. Thanks asawyer for the link.